# validate input field only contains numbers and decimal (money format)

Tags: php, forms, validation

I know this prob a really simple question..  I just need a pay to validate a text input field on my form.  I know I can use the number type for HTML5 and have looked at prey_replace but I don't understand that function for the life of me..

What is the best way for me to validate a input field in my form? PHP, JQuery, Other?  Just want to make sure what is inserted in the text field is in money format like 00.00 (I have set the maxlength of the text input to 5) I just need to check now to make sure only numbers or number and decimal is the only thing submitted when the form submits..

This may be overkill for what I need it for but I did find this fiddle from another question: http://jsfiddle.net/vY39r/11/  However I can't get it to work and I made sure the names match.

Here is a basic example of what I have:

```
<form name="setPrices" action="" method="POST">

<fieldset>
<label for="lowPrice">Low Resolution:</label>
<input type="text" class="price" id="lowPrice" name="lowPrice" value="<?php echo $low_price; ?>" maxlength="5" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label for="mediumPrice">Medium Resolution:</label>
<input type="text" class="price" id="mediumPrice" name="mediumPrice" value="<?php echo $medium_price; ?>" maxlength="5" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label for="highPrice">High Resolution:</label>
<input type="text" class="price" id="highPrice" name="highPrice" value="<?php echo $high_price; ?>" maxlength="5" />
</fieldset>

<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />

<button type="submit" id="submit" class="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: doesn't matter how you end up doing it, the validation ultimately **MUST** be performed on the server. If you depend on client-side logic to validate the form, SOMEONE will bypass the validation and send over garbage.

Comment: Using the sample jsFiddle you provided - http://jsfiddle.net/vY39r/11/ - just change the selector from `$("#amount")` to `$(".price")`. Then validate on the PHP side to make sure it is still a valid submission

Comment: @Sean, I tried changing it to .price but it still didn't work for me like it did in the fiddle.. Im sure it was just user error but technically I could disable JS on the browser and bypass that right?  I was thinking something with PHP would be a better alternative

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/DEVe8/ All I did was post your form (without the `<?php echo $low_price; ?>`) and change `#amount` to `.price`. But yes, you will want to do it on server-side as well as js is very easy to turn off or bypass. Doing it with js makes the client-side a little nicer, but you can never trust it completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    $_POST['lowPrice']=preg_replace('/[^0-9\.\-]+/','',$_POST['lowPrice']);

//...

?>
```

Edit: Capitalised your P in lowPrice for clarity...

Comment: Thanks, that did it..  Can you explain the '/[^0-9\.\-]+/' part of this?  That is where I get confused when using preg_replace.. Where do those characters come from or how do you know which ones to use?

Comment: @Derek - That part is a regex, which aren't easy and take a lot of patience to get your head around at first. Google "regex syntax" or look for the same at php.net for more info.

Comment: This also happens to allow phone numbers (`888-555-1212`), version numbers (`5.5.9`), a single `-` or `.`, etc.  Some additional filtering and/or validation (like a call to `is_numeric`, for example) is essential if validity matters.

Comment: Yes, the above can be used to validate a lot of numeric input. You can tailor it to your needs better by expanding your knowledge with the references to Google and php.net given.

Comment: How about using is_float() ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the regular expression `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$` to check whether the input is in money format or not.

You can use the following code in php to check whether the input matches the above regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$/', $_POST['lowPrice'])) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Do this for all the validation you need to do for checking whether the input is in money format or not.

The description of the regular expression is given below:

```
^ : Assert position at the beginning of the string 
[0-9]+ : Match a single character in the range between "0" and "9" 
   + : Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) 
(\.[0-9]{2})? : Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 
   ? : Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) 
   \. : Match the character "." literally 
   [0-9]{2} : Match a single character in the range between "0" and "9" 
      {2} : Exactly 2 times 
$ : Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Comment: very good answer and explanation, thank you so much!

Comment: You don't need the capturing "()" brackets and entering a value less than 1 (such as .99 for cents will fail. Also, expecting human input, you need to compensate: [-+]?[0-9]*\.|,?[0-9]{0,2} is more effective taking into account a comma as a thousand separator, decimals after a stop, etc, there are many connotations depending on what you want...